# Кликнуть элемент из DropDownMenu

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

Не получается кликнуть по элементу из DropDownMenu.
Получаю исключение NoSuchElementException хотя по локатору эго находит.
Подскажите где промах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 class LanguagePage
    {
        private string _languageDropeDownMenu = "//button[@class='button select__button button_theme_normal button_arrow_down button_size_m i-bem button_js_inited']";
        private string _ukrainLanguageButton = "//option[@value='uk'][1]";        
        private string _saveLanguageButtonLocator = "//button[@class='button form__save button_theme_action button_size_m i-bem button_js_inited']";


        public void ClickLanguageMenu(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_languageDropeDownMenu)).Click();
        }

        public void SelectEnglishLanguage(IWebDriver driver) //Проблема тут.
        {
              WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
             wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath(_ukrainLanguageButton))).Click();
        }

        public void ClickSaveLanguageButton(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_saveLanguageButtonLocator)).Click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `By.Name(_ukrainLanguageButton)` => `By.XPath(_ukrainLanguageButton)`?

Comment: @aepot ))Этот момент исправил но не помогло, все равно не кликает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По выпадающему списку как оказалось так же можно двигаться используя кнопки.

```
 Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
```